# Storing a binary search tree in an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to take a binary search tree, with n elements and store them in an arraylist. Currently, where they are stored in the arraylist is based on, with the root of the tree being element 1, (p = index of their parent in the array) the left child will be at index p*2, and the right child will be at index p*2+1.

Currently I try do do this using this code:

```
public static void arraywriter(TreeNode<String> node) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    int pos = 1;
    outputform.set(pos, node.getElement());
    pos = pos*2;
    if(node.getLeft() != null) {
        arraywriter(node.getLeft());
    }
    pos = pos+1;
    if(node.getRight() != null) {
        arraywriter(node.getRight());
    }
}
```

Whats wrong with my logic? How would I make this work?
Currently if I use this, then try to print out the contents of outputform (which is the name of the arraylist, it has a base size of 10,000) I get: index one returning as null, and the rest being "n" which was what I initialized every element too.

Thanks!

Comment: One problem is that you're currently setting `pos` to 1 at the start of `arraywriter` so its value will be 1 each time. You probably want to add `pos` as a parameter to `arraywriter` so that it can be called with `pos * 2` and `pos*2+1` and then you'll make the initial call to `arraywriter` with `pos` of 1.

Comment: Hey thanks! I cant believe I missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always using the fixed value of 1 for the pos, which means you overwrite it again and again.

Consider using something similar to this:

```
public static void arraywriter(TreeNode<String> node, int pos) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    outputform.set(pos, node.getElement());
    pos = pos*2;
    if(node.getLeft() != null) {
        arraywriter(node.getLeft(), pos);
    }
    pos = pos+1;
    if(node.getRight() != null) {
        arraywriter(node.getRight(), pos);
    }
}
```